# SharePoint note programmatically write error

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

My question relates to programmatically writing to a Sharepoint list field of the type "Note".  Reading from the field is straightforward.

```
//Retrieving the list row
SPListItem baseItem = baseList.GetItemById(itemId) as SPListItem;  

string value = Convert.ToString(baseItem["NameOfTheNoteField"]);
```

But then I try to write to to a Note field;

```
SPListItem item ...;
item["NameOfTheNoteField"] = "MyValue";
```

It results in the following error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range ...

What does the Note field expect if not a string!?

Comment: Is `NameOfTheNoteField` the display name or the internal name?

Answer (score 1):

You actually shouldn't think of it as a *Note* field, but a [`SPMultiLineText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.aspx) field.

To update it you first need to get the current value and edit that - also you shouldn't use `Convert.ToString()` with it but `GetFieldValueAsHtml` or `GetFieldValueAsText`.
Ultimately your way of setting the value should have worked. `Value does not fall within the expected range` could also be coming from somewhere else - e.g. you are not using the correct name of the field and hence `item["NameofNoteField"]` is throwing an error. Try to debug it.

Taking your example and updating the current text in the field:

```
SPListItem baseItem = baseList.GetItemById(itemId) as SPListItem;
SPFieldMultiLineText mlfield = baseItem.Fields.GetField("NameOfTheNoteField") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
string fieldtext = multilineField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(item["NameOfTheNoteField"], baseItem );
//or use GetFieldValueAsText
fieldtext += "I am the update of the text";
baseItem ["NameOfTheNoteField"] = fieldtext;
baseItem.Update()
```